# When does a strongloop promise execute the database call?

Tags: api, ecmascript-6, promise, loopback

I was refactoring someone elses code.

```
let promiseObj = Application.models.Widget.findById(connection.childId)

    if (connection.child != 'Widget') {
        typeES = "media"
        promiseObj = Application.models.Media.findById(connection.childId)
    }

promiseObj.then((obj) => {
  let ownerId = obj.ownerId
  let promiseUser = Application.models.MyUser.findById(ownerId)
})
```

The question is, does the server get called when 
"let promiseObj = Application.models.Widget.findById(connection.childId)" is declared.

Or does the server get called when the .then is declared as the promise have a way to be fulfilled.

This is loopback with ES6.

Thanks guys/girls :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Erazihel is explaining, the declaration does not fire the resolve, it is called when you call .then()

I made a simple example in order to visualize the effect, there you will check that the time of the resolve matches the time where you call .then(), not on declaration.

```
p1.then(
    // Then calls the resolve so the execution time 'resolve' matches .then
    function(val) {
        var timeMeAgain =  new Date().toLocaleString();
      log.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', val.thisPromiseCount +
        ') Promise done, then is called here (<small>Async call finished, .then called at: '+timeMeAgain+', promise executed at": '+val.timeCalledAt+' </small>)<br/>');
    })
```

[Check the example code here](https://jsfiddle.net/moplin/hmdac13y/)

*Code is based in the MDN example. Check documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

---

**EDIT**

About the resolve method, as the MDN documentation explains:

> The method returns a Promise object that is resolved with the given value.
>   If the value is a thenable (i.e. has a "then" method), the returned
>   promise will "follow" that thenable, adopting its eventual state;
>   otherwise the returned promise will be fulfilled with the value.

Meaning that the response object will be returned when the Database or endpoint returns the information, *not on declaration of the promise*.

Comment: i just realized how little i know about this

Comment: Rafael, I just added some info about resolve, it should help a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the server get called when `let promiseObj = Application.models.Widget.findById(connection.childId)` is declared.

Yes, the server request is made as soon as the `findById` method is called.

> Or does the server get called when the .then is declared as the promise have a way to be fulfilled.

`then` is just a method that is *called*, there is no declaration here. And it doesn't "give the promise a way to be fulfilled" - the promise will *always* resolve when the request finishes (fulfill in case of success and reject in case of an error), regardless whether there are any callbacks or not.
If you install a callback via `then`, it will be called when the promise is fulfilled.

---

So yes, I'm pretty certain that you should refactor this code:

```
let promiseObj;
if (connection.child != 'Widget') {
    promiseObj = Application.models.Widget.findById(connection.childId);
} else {
    typeES = "media"
    promiseObj = Application.models.Media.findById(connection.childId)
}

let promiseUser = promiseObj.then((obj) => {
    return Application.models.MyUser.findById(obj.ownerId);
});
```

Comment: It's very interesting what you say, still I am not totally sure. I need something more visual. I will try to make a better code example to understand when the endpoint/server is hit.

Comment: You can try to drop the `then` for a while and check your devtools whether the server is still hit. In your original code, two request will be made unless it's a widget, and only one of the results will be used.